# Reflection returning extension methods that "aren't defined"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, .net-4.6

I'm running .net 4.6 application.

I'm using reflection to find the extension method `ToHashSet`

This method [was introduced in .net 4.7.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tohashset?view=netframework-4.7.2#applies-to), and "does not" exist in 4.6

[image]

The following program succeeds. It's able to find and reflect upon this non-existent method.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;

namespace TestAppNS
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var toHashSet = GetExtensionMethods(typeof(Enumerable)).First(x => x.Name == "ToHashSet");
        }

        private static IEnumerable<MethodInfo> GetExtensionMethods(Type type) {
            return
                from method in type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                where method.IsDefined(typeof(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute), false)
                select method;
        }
    }
}
```

Why is that happening?

Is there a way to detect this by looking at the `MethodInfo` object or something else?

Comment: Is it not the case that your application targets 4.6 but the framework you are running this on is 4.7.2 so reflection finds the method because it is in fact there

Comment: It does not find it for me and i am on 4.6. [here a fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1taseG)

Comment: If it finds it, it must be there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While your application targets framework version 4.6 all that means is thats the minimum version of the framework it can run against. This targeting essentially tells the compiler what 'APIs' are available when you developing and when you compile your program but remember reflection has no compile time safety. It just does what you tell it at run time and you hope it works.

In your example the framework version your are running on (not targeting) is 4.7.2. I know this because you found a method via reflection that is only present on 4.7.2